# Eclipse compiling error for C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, compiler-errors

I just switched from mac to pc and I have to instaled Eclipse for my C++ programing and compiling. I have also instaled Cygwin64 and added the path and things like that. according to the internet it should work now but I get this error:

> Problem Occured 'Launching test Debug' has encountered a problem. Error starting process.

In this message 'test' is the name of the class I try to run. Before running I ofcourse Build my project so that is not the problem.

Acording to eclipse there is also an error in the debug map in the makefile file on line 44: @echo 'Building target: $@' (this is what the message says)

My operating system is windows 8 64 bit.

Thanks for reading

Comment: It means there was some error in starting executable. It could mean that some paths are wrong or there is no permission to run that executable or some of the dlls are missing. In such situation I always try to run executable directly either from elevated cmd prompt or from windows explorer. Please try to run the executable built by eclipse project and post the error message.

Comment: I don't get how to do that. What do I search in Windows Explorer

Comment: Open    windows explorer and go to the path were executable will be generated after the build. You can get path of the executable from Eclipse. Check project properties->'C/C++ build'->Logging . This will give you log file name and it will have all the steps carried out by eclipse. Then Open that path in windows explorer and double click on executable generated.

Comment: there is no exe file just 3 text files and an xml. what do i have to do. here is the text in the test.build file: http://pastebin.com/2V1ivhsY